# Definition of optional sigma algebra require the left hand limit or just right continuous adapted processes?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

While reading the following post : https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/08/filtrations-and-adapted-processes/

I have come across a question on the definition of optional and predictable processes. In most books I have read before, optional sigma algebra is defined as the sigma algebra generated by cadlag adapted processes, and predictable sigma algebra is defined as the sigma algebra generated by caglad adapted processes or in some books just left continuous adapted processes.

In George's post he defines both as just right-continuous  or left-continuous adapted processes. In the predictable case, I can see that both are in fact the same as it is generated by continuous adapted processes. However, in the case of optional sigma algebra I am not sure if they are the same. Does the omission of left-limit here matter?

Comment: You might leave this question as a comment on George Lowther's blog he answers frequently

Answer (score 2):

Generally, on a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, 
\mathbf{F}=(\mathscr{F}_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}_+},\mathsf{P})$, no matter the completeness of
$\mathbf{F}$, the optional sigma algebra $\mathscr{O}(\mathbf{F})$ is generated by the
càdlàg adapted  processes.

Also, the following theorem is important: (cf.  C. Dellacherie & P. Meyer, *Probabilities and Potential*, volume 29 of *North-Holland Mathematics Studies*.
North-Holland, Amsterdam, (1978), p.124, Th.VI.65)

**Theorem**: Under the usual conditions, the optional $\sigma$-field is also generated by the
right-continuous processes adapted to the $\mathbf{F}$.

Due to this theorem, the definition in above mentioned post, is also reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The books quoted from in the following links were the ultimate bibles of stochastic processes when I was a student:

- The [optional sigma algebra](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Optional_sigma-algebra) ${\cal O}(\boldsymbol F)$ is generated by the ***càdlàg adapted processes***.
- The [predictable sigma algebra](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Predictable_sigma-algebra) ${\cal P}(\boldsymbol F)$ is by the ***adapted*** processes that are ***continuous from the left*** (not necessarily with limits from the right).

Interestingly, ${\cal P}(\boldsymbol F)\subset  {\cal O}(\boldsymbol F)\,.$